# how to open a map activity from home page android studio java

Tags: java, android

I want to have a secondary activity which will be a map activity that can be opened by a button click on the main menu of an app. So I am using the built in map activity in android studio and when I try and launch that alone the map works. But when I try to add a main home page with button and then use that button to launch the map it doesn't work and my app closes. Does anyone know the correct way to launch a normal map from a button. I have all the implementations in the gradle files correct. I will include my manifest and main activity below.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1,container,false);


        bt = v.findViewById(R.id.launchmap);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package = "com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.default.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="come.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBgSEI9Xvh3TicLaNj8FigA4iRyP1jdEVs" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start

#Android_map

Comment: Ive already done this and gotten it to work. Im asking how do I navigate to this map activity on a button click from a different activity.

Comment: String value="Hello world";
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);    
i.putExtra("key",value);
startActivity(i);

Comment: Use the pass your data from frist activity to another activity , and got this data to use map longitude lattitude

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers - they are not valid answers. Also: best not to tell people something is "so simple" - that doesn't help (especially since, if it was "so simple" - nobody would be asking about it). I removed that from your question. Also: not sure what the hashtag is for, since that's not really a thing on Stack Overflow.